# insert data into SQL table without commands

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

I use sql server 2008. I dont want to insert using commands. Can i type the values for any column through management studio instead ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can right click on any table and choose Edit Top X Rows.  This will bring up an editable table of the records where you can insert and edit rows.

If you need to edit more than the top 200, which is the default, you can edit the sql user to fetch the rows by right clicking below the tab and choosing Panes -> SQL.  With this pane open, you can edit the sql to return a different resultset to edit.